# Accessing FoxPro 2.6 from C#

Tags: c#, wcf, foxpro

I have a need to access data stored in a FoxPro 2.6 application using a modern application.

I had assumed that I would access said data in FoxPro using an ODBC Dataconnection and that my weapon of choice would be a WCF service.

Call comes in from 3rd party application; hit service. Service polls FoxPro database and returns the results. Firstly does this sound sound?

Secondly it is more complicated than that. It seems that there are procedures in the FoxPro app that PROCESS the data and return the processed result.

Are there any ways to do this?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to update the FoxPro app.  We were faced with the same dilemma a few years back, and never found any other option.  Reading from the tables is straightforward, and there is info on connecting to them at connectionstrings.com, but the procedures got buggy.  Here's to hoping you have better luck.

Comment: OK - so one option might be to carve out the procedures we need into a modern foxpro app and calling that? it is all read-only so we ought to be able to point it at the same data files...? Oh and Thank you :)

Comment: @JonH - Modern FoxPro, considering Microsoft has not supported FoxPro for more then 6 years, modern FoxPro is not possible.  Going forward there is and will NEVER be x64 support.  I would look for an alternative today before x86 is discontinued.

Comment: Just for clarity, Visual FoxPro 9 SP2 will be supported by Microsoft 'through 2015' which I assume is American for 'until the end of 2015'.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if this is FoxPro 2.6 (DOS) or FoxPro 2.6a (Windows) but either way I don't like your chances.

I would suggest you get the data out and put it into a database that is easy for you to access. FoxPro should allow you to export the data to several other formats, especially if you use a newer version of Visual FoxPro to open the old FoxPro database. Procedures are just code that can be changed over as well.

It's a one time pain that will save you **so much time** down the road.

Also, FoxPro databases are quite easy to get corrupted so I would suggest you make sure it's backed up!

Comment: Hi it is FoxPro 2.6a. It is completely out of my hands to move this platform forward. The solution I am working towards is ODBC access for the raw data and a custom separate app with identical procedures for the derived data which accepts inputs and returns the data via a file.

Comment: Like I said, you're better off writing a VFP layer in between to convert the data to CSV or something similar. Even if you have to do this every time you want to access the data.

Alternatively, you can just access the file directly. The structure is mapped here: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~TableFileStructure

Both of the above is still easier and more robust than getting ODBC to work reliably, imo.